# Python unexpected StopIteration

Tags: python, iterator, generator, operator-precedence, assign

This is my code

```
class A:
    pass

def f():
    yield A()

def g():
    it = f()
    next(it).a = next(it, None)

g()
```

that produces the `StopIteration` error, caused by `next(it).a = next(it, None)`. Why?

The documentation says that [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=next#next) function does not raise the `StopIteration` if the default value is provided, and I expected it to get me the first item from the generator (the `A` instance) and set the `a` attribute to `None`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `f` only yields a single value, you can only call `next` on it once.

The right hand side of your expression (`next(it, None)`) is evaluated *before* the left hand side, and thus exhausts the generator.

Calling `next(it).a` on the left hand side will then raise `StopIteration`.

Answer (score 5):

Your `f()` generator function yields just **one** value. After that it is exhausted and raises `StopIteration`.

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> def f():
...     yield A()
... 
>>> generator = f()
>>> generator
<generator object f at 0x10be771f8>
>>> next(generator)
<__main__.A object at 0x10be76f60>
>>> next(generator)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

That's because there is *no loop* in `f()` to yield more than once, a generator function does not, on its own, loop, just because you can use it *in* a loop.

Note that for an assignment, Python executes the right-hand-side expression *first*, before figuring out what to assign it *to*. So the `next(it, None)` is called first, the `next(it).a` for the assignment is called *second*.

The body of the `f()` function is executed just like any other Python function, with the addition of *pausing*. `next()` on the generator un-pauses the code, and the code then runs until the next `yield` statement is executed. That statement then pauses the generator again. If the function instead *ends* (returns), `StopIteration` is raised.

In your `f()` generator that means:

1. when you call `f()` a new generator object is created. The function body is paused.
2. you call `next()` on it the first time. The code starts running, creates an instance of `A()` and yields that instance. The function is paused again.
3. you call `next()` on it a second time. The code starts running, reaches the end of the function, and returns. `StopIteration` is raised.

If you add a loop to `f()`, or simply add a *second* `yield` line, your code works:

```
def f():
    yield A()
    yield A()
```

or

```
def f():
    while True:
        yield A()
```